# Mysql column having json type is not transform to flatten in kafka connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect

I have json column in mysql 'meta' I want to flatten key from the json . but it's not working .

example:
{
"meta": {
"first": "David",
"middle": null,
"last": "Wong"
}
}

I want to meta.first = "David"

I want to sync data from one mysql database to other mysql database using kafka connector.

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `json_column->>'$.meta.first'` See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

Comment: Hi @SelVazi  I am using kafka connect for synching data from one sql database to other database. In source database I have a meta column which is json type . I need to extract some field from the meta json and sync the extracted filed to target database.